# scala case class update value inside map

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap, case-class

I have:

```
var targets = mutable.HashMap[String, WordCount]()
```

Where WordCount is a case class:

```
case class WordCount(name: String,
                 id: Int,
                 var count: Option[Double]) {

def withCount(v: Double) : WordCount = copy(count = Some(v))
}
```

And I'm trying to update the values for count each time the key exists in the map,

```
def insert(w1: String, w2: String, count: Double) = {
    if(targets.contains(w1)){
      var wc = targets.get(w1).getOrElse().asInstanceOf[WordCount]
      wc.withCount(9.0)
    } else{
      targets.put(w1, WordCount(w1, idT(), Some(0.0))
    }
}
```

But it does not working. What is the proper way to do that? please!

Comment: What is 'not working'? Is it not compiling? Is the program not correct aka word counts are right?

Comment: why 9.0 in `withCount(9.0)`? And `insert` doesn't use its `count` argument

Comment: I just wanted to update that value. Correct would be `wc.count + count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `withCount` does not modify the case class instance but creates a new one. Therefore, you'll have to store the newly created instance in the map again:

```
def insert(w1: String, w2: String, count: Double) = {
  val newWC = targets.get(w1).fold {
    WordCount(w1, idT(), Some(0.0)
  } { oldWC =>
    oldWC.withCount(9.0)
  }
  targets.put(w1, newWC)
}
```

Note the `targets.get(w1).fold`: Get returns an `Option[WordCount]`, `fold` calls its first parameter, if its receiver is a `None`, otherwise (i.e. its a `Some`) it calls the second parameter and passes it the value the `Some` contains.